# I am trying to create a JSP Page with frames

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets, frameset

I am trying to create a JSP page which will contain multiple section. Each section will contain data fetched from data base using servlet. I tried using frame and have put frame src ="servlet" and in servlet data is being fetched and forward that to jsp which I want to be displayed inside the frame?? Anyone having some idea for this.

Comment: I tried above but it is not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

I often want to achieve similar things and do so by setting attributes on the HttpServletRequest object.

**Servlet:**

```
User user = userBean.getUser(231); 
Job job = user.getJob();

request.setAttribute("user",user);
request.setAttribute("job",job);

request.getRequestDispatcher( url ).forward(request, response);
```

**JSP Page**

```
<div id="section1">
    ${user.name} 
    ${user.age}
</div>

<div id="section2">
    ${job.title} 
    ${job.wage}
</div>
```

**Notes**

Frame is an old HTML Element and [not compatible with HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp)
I've used divs in my example, but you could use HTML5 [Section](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/) to provide more smeantic meaning.

Hope I've understood your problem and this helps.

Good luck

Adam

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. My question was how to transfer data from distinct servlets into distinct frames in single HTML page. Anyways I figured out a way now I am using divs instead of frames with tables and I passed data using session. I worked out for me and thanks for help

Comment: Ah I see, the original question doesn't give the impression of multiple servlets, just multiple sections of the jsp page.  Glad you've solved it.  :-)